# How to prevent from repeated y-axis and hide label in google chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using google column chart but there an issues that is repeated y-axis value and unable to hide right label. And i cannot figure out these issues. Please see below image for more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason the vAxis labels repeat has to do with format

the numbers have decimal places that aren't being shown

add a format, to the chart options, that includes decimal places, e.g.

```
vAxis: {
  format: '#,##0.00'
}
```

or custom labels / ticks can be provided...

```
vAxis: {
  ticks: [0, 1, 2]
}
```

---

to hide the legend...

```
legend: {
  position: 'none'
}
```

Comment: hope this helps, assuming you are using --> `packages: ['corechart']`